# Foundation CSS not working with Internet Explorer 9 only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I just implemented the Foundation CSS framework which works great in all browsers except IE 9. In IE 10+ it works great, but not in IE 9. I have tried a variety of fixes, the latest adding  and  tags surrounding my code, but still no luck. I can't seem to find out any issues with compatibility so I'm hoping there is a fix.

Comment: What specifically are the issues in IE9?

Comment: And do you have javascript error in console debugger ? Or error of file (css/js) loading ?

Comment: @winhowes the grid is not working as expected and neither is some of the inline styles.

Comment: @general03 no js errors in console and works fine in every other browser

Comment: Can you put your grid code please !